# Why is Nodemon server crashing when trying to start Mongo server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I am new to creating nodejs application. I am trying to get started with simple angular, and nodejs application. I have saved my data in "mLab". Now when I am trying to display my data through this below code, my nodemon server is crashing describing,

> "MongoError: failed to connect to server [ds030817.mlab.com:30817]".

Here is my code I have copied from other source.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('mongodb://<dbuser> 
    <dbpassword>@ds030817.mlab.com:30817/user_data_0001',['books']);


router.get('/tasks', function(req, res, next){
db.books.find(function(err, books){
    if(err){
        res.send(err);
    }
    res.json(books);
})
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Did you try to connect to the mongo endpoint using something like studio3t or a mongodb gui app?

Comment: missing colon `:` between `<dbuser>` and `<dbpassword>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string format is not right. Use following

```
var db = mongojs('mongodb://dbuser:dbpassword@ds030817.mlab.com:30817/user_data_0001',['books']);
```

Comment: If your system have mongo shell then fire terminal in your system and run this command: 
mongo mongodb://dbuser:dbpassword@ds030817.mlab.com:30817/user_data_0001 and let me know you are able to connect or not

Comment: well, connection is failing. I should check again.

Comment: Just check your server allows 30817 port. If not open 30817 port.